# Error trying to install npm for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm having a stab at learning Node.js and I'm having a few issues when installing NPM (Node Package Manager). I'm pretty sure it's either a permissions thing or folder thing... please note that I've just purchased a Mac (I've used Windows all my life) and I'm pretty unfamiliar with the Mac terminal.

Okay, I went to use the one line install for NPM: `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` and I got an error...

```
All clean!
! [ -d .git ] || git submodule update --init --recursive
node cli.js rm npm -g -f
node cli.js install -g -f
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___npm.npm
npm ERR! error installing npm@1.0.94 Error: EACCESS, Undefined error: 0 '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! Error: EACCESS, Undefined error: 0 '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/private/var/folders/z2/f05c8hx105g79drh6r7hr01w0000gn/T/npm.1219/package/cli.js" "install" "-g" "-f"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/z2/f05c8hx105g79drh6r7hr01w0000gn/T/npm.1219/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.9-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.94
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCESS
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/z2/f05c8hx105g79drh6r7hr01w0000gn/T/npm.1219/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
make: *** [install] Error 1
npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___npm.npm
npm ERR! error installing npm@1.0.94 Error: EACCESS, Undefined error: 0 '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! Error: EACCESS, Undefined error: 0 '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/z2/f05c8hx105g79drh6r7hr01w0000gn/T/npm.1219/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/z2/f05c8hx105g79drh6r7hr01w0000gn/T/npm.1219/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.5.9-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.94
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCESS
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/z2/f05c8hx105g79drh6r7hr01w0000gn/T/npm.1219/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
It failed
```

there's obviously a folder issue here, perhaps I'm installing in the wrong place, my node folder is at Users/Mike/node, when I try and find out my node path variable using NODE_PATH I get the following error:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ Mike$ node node/NODE_PATH  

node.js:203
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Mike/node/NODE_PATH'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:195:26)
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to add the node path like such:

```
$ export PATH=/path/to/node/0.n.y/bin:${PATH}
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Or am I confusing myself?

Comment: maybe this need a root privilege?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /usr/local`?

Comment: Hi there, the output of ls -al /usr/local is

drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  238  5 Oct 18:48 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 root  wheel  476 13 Sep 22:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  238  5 Oct 18:48 bin
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 27 Sep 20:50 git
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102  5 Oct 18:48 include
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102  5 Oct 18:48 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102  8 Sep 23:41 share

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The permissions on `/usr/local` require you to use `sudo` to install NPM, or change your permissions. Of these three, **I recommend the third option**.

#### Option #1: Use `sudo`

(Note that the the creator of NPM [advises against using this method](http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Permission-Errors-on-Installation))

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

#### Option #2: Change permissions

```
sudo chmod g+rwx /usr/local
sudo chgrp admin /usr/local
```

#### Option #3: Use Homebrew

I recommend [installing Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) to manage installing *nix tools on OS X (I'd stay away from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) & [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/)). Installing Homebrew will set the permissions for `/usr/local` so you can write to it without `sudo`. You can then install Node via Homebrew, and then install NPM normally:

```
brew install node --without-npm
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: Curious why you mention staying away from MacPorts and Fink?

Comment: @Zenox They're a bit overzealous about needlessly installing dependencies that OS X already comes with perfectly suitable versions of. Homebrew also advocates not using `sudo` and installing in the proper location: `/usr/local`. Fink's website also seems to be very broken at the moment.

Comment: You need to add `--without-npm` to brew install, see `brew info node`

Comment: The option #3 is now changed, I added a new answer, feel free to update yours :)

Comment: Looks like they have moved the file.. if you get a 301 error try "sudo curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh"

Answer (score 0):

Use `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`.

Edit: You're using node -v v0.5.9-pre, which is very unstable. Use 0.4.12, the latest stable version.

Comment: (although it makes isaacs unhappy)

Comment: As @thejh mentioned, and I mention in my answer, the creator of NPM [advises against using `sudo`](http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Permission-Errors-on-Installation) to install NPM.

Comment: Just ran the following and got the following:


Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ Mike$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
Password:  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6353  100  6353    0     0   6495      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14276

then the cursor comes back?

Comment: @MikeSav hmm, that's a weird issue. I'd ask in #node.js on freenode, and if nobody can help you there, post an issue at https://github.com/isaacs/npm .

Comment: @AndrewMarshall well, and everyone does it anyway.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall if you run stuff from the internet under your account, it'll eventually be able to get elevated rights at some time. For example, the next time you use sudo.

Comment: @thejh that's true, but I don't remember the last time I ran `sudo` on my personal machine; it's used quite often when I shell into a server though, but those times are few and far apart (thankfully).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall well, a virus could also grab your password when you enter it in the screensaver and then pass it on to sudo.

Comment: @thejh well anything's possible… but if the machine is already compromised there's not much that's going to protect you, the point is to make it harder to *become* compromised. Anyway, major digression here :) (oh look, stackoverflow now yells at you for an "extended discussion" in comments)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows , it takes some steps , 1) create a file called package.json

{
  "name": "hello"
, "version": "0.0.1"
, "dependencies": {
    "express": "*"
  }
}
where hello is the name of the package and * means the latest version of your dependency

2) code to you project directory and run the following command

npm install

Answer (score 0):

As update for the method #3 on OSX the correct command now is:

```
brew install node --without-npm
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option #4:**

Install node local to the user that needs it.

I should clarify for my purposes I needed npm to install appium on an OSX server running Bamboo for our integrated testing. I only had macports available and rather than installing homebrew to manage just the one package I decided to build it from source and install it local to the bamboo user. Which allowed us to run appium as the bamboo user and made it possible to run our appium tests on Bamboo as a not very privileged user.

[This guide from Tom Novelli](http://tnovelli.net/blog/blog.2011-08-27.node-npm-user-install.html)  goes over how to do it. The basic gist is:

```
# Make the dir to hold the installation of node
cd
mkdir ./local
mkdir sources
# Tell npm about your new non-default directories
vi .npmrc 
cd sources
# Get node and do the typical source install procedure
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.29/node-v0.10.29.tar.gz
tar xf node-v0.10.29.tar.gz
cd node-v8.10.29/
# Important part is the --prefix
./configure --prefix=~/.local
make
make install
# Make a link so node doesn't get confused
cd
ln -s .local/lib/node_modules .node_modules
# Edit PATH to include ~/.local
vi .bashrc
```

*.npmrc*

```
root =    /home/YOUR-USERNAME/.local/lib/node_modules
binroot = /home/YOUR-USERNAME/.local/bin
manroot = /home/YOUR-USERNAME/.local/share/man
```

*.bashrc OR .profile OR whereever you like setting your path*

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

**Useful Links**

The [.npmrc](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npmrc.html) man page useful.

And just in case here's a link to [node source](http://nodejs.org/download/).